# Filter latest records based on condition on columns

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Here is my input data frame

```
DataPartition   TimeStamp   OrganizationId  SegmentId   GeographicSegment_geographyId   IsSubtracted    Sequence    FFAction|!|
Japan   2018-05-29T09:17:18+00:00   4295876592  27  100002  false   1   O|!|
Japan   2018-05-29T07:52:45+00:00   4295876592  23  null    null    null    D|!|
Japan   2018-05-29T09:17:18+00:00   4295876592  28  100025  false   1   O|!|
Japan   2018-05-29T08:05:17+00:00   4295876592  14  null    null    null    D|!|
Japan   2018-05-29T09:17:18+00:00   4295876592  26  100105  false   1   O|!|
Japan   2018-05-29T09:17:18+00:00   4295876592  6   100131  false   2   O|!|
Japan   2018-05-29T09:17:18+00:00   4295876592  27  112018  false   2   O|!|
Japan   2018-05-29T09:17:18+00:00   4295876592  11  null    null    null    D|!|
Japan   2018-05-29T09:17:18+00:00   4295876592  6   100023  false   1   O|!|
Japan   2018-05-29T08:05:17+00:00   4295876592  25  null    null    null    D|!|
Japan   2018-05-29T09:17:18+00:00   4295876592  29  100029  false   1   O|!|
Japan   2018-05-29T08:05:17+00:00   4295876592  24  null    null    null    D|!|
Japan   2018-05-29T07:52:45+00:00   4295876592  22  null    null    null    D|!|
Japan   2018-05-29T09:11:00+00:00   4295876592  27  100020  false   2   O|!|
Japan   2018-05-29T08:05:17+00:00   4295876592  7   100148  false   1   O|!|
Japan   2018-05-29T08:05:17+00:00   4295876592  21  null    null    null    D|!|
```

And the logic is that for the same `OrganizationId` and `SegmentId` columns i need to get the latest record based on order by 
TimeStamp column but with one condition 
Condition is if for the same `OrganizationId` and `SegmentId` we get one `TimeStamp` then i need to get that 
but if i get more than one TimeStamp row then only i need to get the latest one .
For example we have three rows for `SegmentId` 27

```
Japan   2018-05-29T09:17:18+00:00   4295876592  27  100002  false   1   O|!|
Japan   2018-05-29T09:17:18+00:00   4295876592  27  112018  false   2   O|!|
Japan   2018-05-29T09:11:00+00:00   4295876592  27  100020  false   2   O|!|
```

So in the above case we have same `OrganizationId` and `SegmentId` but two `TimeStamp` so i need to get the latest two 
and the expected output will be

```
Japan   2018-05-29T09:17:18+00:00   4295876592  27  100002  false   1   O|!|
Japan   2018-05-29T09:17:18+00:00   4295876592  27  112018  false   2   O|!|
```

But in an other scenario we have two records  for `SegmentId` 6

```
Japan   2018-05-29T09:17:18+00:00   4295876592  6   100131  false   2   O|!|
Japan   2018-05-29T09:17:18+00:00   4295876592  6   100023  false   1   O|!|
```

In this case also `OrganizationId` and `SegmentId` are same but we have only time stamp so i need to retain both columns

And finally this is my Ouptut data frame

```
DataPartition   TimeStamp   OrganizationId  SegmentId   GeographicSegment_geographyId   IsSubtracted    Sequence    FFAction|!|
Japan   2018-05-29T09:17:18+00:00   4295876592  27  100002  false   1   O|!|
Japan   2018-05-29T07:52:45+00:00   4295876592  23  null    null    null    D|!|
Japan   2018-05-29T09:17:18+00:00   4295876592  28  100025  false   1   O|!|
Japan   2018-05-29T08:05:17+00:00   4295876592  14  null    null    null    D|!|
Japan   2018-05-29T09:17:18+00:00   4295876592  26  100105  false   1   O|!|
Japan   2018-05-29T09:17:18+00:00   4295876592  6   100131  false   2   O|!|
Japan   2018-05-29T09:17:18+00:00   4295876592  27  112018  false   2   O|!|
Japan   2018-05-29T09:17:18+00:00   4295876592  11  null    null    null    D|!|
Japan   2018-05-29T09:17:18+00:00   4295876592  6   100023  false   1   O|!|
Japan   2018-05-29T08:05:17+00:00   4295876592  25  null    null    null    D|!|
Japan   2018-05-29T09:17:18+00:00   4295876592  29  100029  false   1   O|!|
Japan   2018-05-29T08:05:17+00:00   4295876592  24  null    null    null    D|!|
Japan   2018-05-29T07:52:45+00:00   4295876592  22  null    null    null    D|!|
Japan   2018-05-29T08:05:17+00:00   4295876592  7   100148  false   1   O|!|
Japan   2018-05-29T08:05:17+00:00   4295876592  21  null    null    null    D|!|
```

Here is my code that i am trying to use but when i use this i miss record with same SegmentId that has same same TimeStamp

```
val windowSpec3 = Window.partitionBy("OrganizationId", "SegmentId", "TimeStamp").orderBy(unix_timestamp($"TimeStamp", "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss").cast("timestamp").desc)
    val latestForEachKey = latestForEachKey2.withColumn("rank", row_number().over(windowSpec3)).filter($"rank" === 1).drop("rank")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove Timestamp from partitionBy and try this:

```
val windowSpec3 = Window.partitionBy("OrganizationId", "SegmentId")
.orderBy(unix_timestamp($"TimeStamp", "yyyy-MM- dd'T'HH:mm:ss").cast("timestamp").desc)

val latestForEachKey = df.withColumn("rank", 
dense_rank().over(windowSpec3)).filter($"rank" === 1).drop("rank")
```

Comment: Still getting three records for SegmentId 27 .I should get only 2